# Metodo de Horner, error de sintaxis

Tags: python, algoritmos

estoy intentando realizar lo siguiente pero no me termina de funcionar del todo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde `d` representa los coeficientes del polinomio de grado `n`. En concreto, `d1` es la constante, mientras que `dn+1` es el coeficiente asociado al término `x^n`.

Se supone que `n<10`. De esta manera, `f(d,1, n+1, x)` devuelve el valor del polinomio (definido por `d`) evaluado en `x`.

El resultado se escribe de evaluar `p(x,d)` con 3 decimales

La entrada esta definida de la siguiente manera:

- La primera línea de la entrada contendrá el grado del polinomio
- La segunda línea contendrá los `n+1` coeficientes (reales) del polinomio `p` a evaluar donde el primer numero es el coeficiente asociado al término de mayor grado y el ultimo la constante del polinomio
- la tercera linea contiene el valor real `x`

:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

def horner(d,inic,fin,x):
    if (inic==fin):
        return d[fin];
    else:
        return d[inic]+ x * horner(d,inic+1,fin,x);


n = int(input())  

# n+1 coeficientes del polinomio de mayor a menor
cadenaEntrada = input()     # Leemos los coeficientes
coeficientes = [0]*(n+1);   # Lista inicializada con n+1 ceros

for i in range(0,n+1):
    coeficientes[i] = float(cadenaEntrada.split(" ")[i])    #guardamos los coeficientes en la lista

x = float(input())  # Leemos el valor real de x

print ("{0:.3f}".format(horner(coeficientes,0,n,x)))  # Imprimimos el resultado
```

Comment: No termina de funcionar del todo... ¿Por qué motivo?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para añadir la información. Si dejas información importante en los comentarios es más dificil que recibas respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consideraciones

Dado que **Python** indexa las listas a partir de cero `0` sugiero trabajar con:

> [image: formula1]

La idea central del [Algoritmo de Horner](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Horner) es reducir el número de multiplicaciones.

Por ejemplo si se tiene: [image: formula2] se requiere de dos multiplicaciones y una suma.

En cambio factorizando: [image: formula3] sólo es necesaria una multiplicación y una suma, de ahí estriba su fortaleza cuando se le emplea en operaciones con intensidad de cálculo.

Como se trata de un `algoritmo recursivo` es mejor proveer un pequeño ejemplo manual para luego ir a su implementación con **Python**.

### Algoritmo de Horner

Se tiene el siguiente polinomio ordenado y completo `p(x)`:

[image: formula4]

> **Spoiler:** `d[3]=4` y `3` también viene a ser el [grado del polinomio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grado_(polinomio)) `p(x)`

Con esta información se puede evaluar el polinomio `p(x)` cuando `x=6` o dicho de otra forma `p(x=6)`:

[image: formula5]

En este caso hay `3 sumas` y `3 multiplicaciones`, en cambio si se reemplaza `6` directamente en el polinomio:

[image: formula6]

Se tiene `8 multiplicaciones` y `3 sumas`, por ejemplo: `6³` se multiplica `3 veces`.

### Python

Visto lo anterior aquí el código para el **Algoritmo recursivo de Horner**:

```
# -------------------------------
# La funcion recursiva de horner
# para operar toma el maximo
# exponente del polinomio
# -------------------------------
# ver que: 1 + len(coef) - 1 
# es: len(coef)
# -------------------------------
def hornerRecursiva(d, ini, fin, x):
    if (ini == fin):
        # 1 coef
        return d[fin]
    else:
        # len(coef)-1
        return d[ini]+ x * hornerRecursiva(d,ini+1,fin,x)
    # 1 + len(coef) - 1 iteraciones


# -------------------------------
# EJEMPLO
# -------------------------------
# Se tiene el polinomio ordenado y completo p(x):
# 4x3 + 5x2 + 1x + 2
# -------------------------------
coef = [4,5,1,2]    # coeficientes
x = 6               # el valor que se usara en el polinomio #p(x=6)
n = len(coef)-1     # maximo exponente de p(x)


# la lista coef tiene que ir al reves si se emplea
# el metodo recursivo
resultado = hornerRecursiva(coef[::-1], 0, n, x)
print('%.2f' % resultado)
#1052.00
# -------------------------------
```

A primera vista no difiere de lo posteado en la pregunta (`a parte de los comentarios claro`) pero nótese el tratamiento que se le da a los coeficientes: `coef[::-1]` van en sentido inverso en la función recursiva.

Esto no pasaría si se empleara un bucle `for` por ejemplo:

```
# -------------------------------
# La funcion 'for' de horner
# -------------------------------
# A diferencia de la funcion
# recursiva se define el rango
# con el numero de coeficientes
# -------------------------------
def hornerBucle(d, ini, fin, x):
    rs = d[ini]                  # resultado es definido al inicio
    for i in range(ini+1, fin):  # empieza en ini+1 porque ya se tomo d[ini]
        rs = d[i] + x * rs
    return rs

coef = [4,5,1,2]    # coeficientes
x = 6               # el valor que se usara en el polinomio #p(x=6)
n = len(coef)       #  todos los coeficientes    


# la lista coef va normal
# se tiene que recorrer toda la lista len(coef)
resultado = hornerBucle(coef, 0, n, x) 
print('%.2f'%resultado)
# -------------------------------
```

Para terminar veo una linea gravitando sola `if __name__ == "__main__":`, creo que se busca la siguiente estructura:

```
# se define una variable de control
# para la funcion main()
__name__ = "main"

def hornerRecursiva(d, ini, fin, x):
    # RESTO CODIGO

def main():
    # SE CAPTURAN LOS PARAMETROS
    resultado = hornerRecursiva(coef[::-1], 0, n, x)
    print('%.2f' % resultado)

# se ejecuta main() 
# siempre y cuando se cumpla
# la condicion
if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Adicionalmente si estás trabajando con **Python>=3** he visto que se puede conseguir una lista de números con un `for`:

```
coef = [float(c) for c in input().split()]
```

Esto último, siento decir que no lo he podido verificar, pero en teoría debería funcionar, en todo caso, considero que sería preferible tratarse lo anterior como una nueva pregunta.